Blender rig creation doesn't work how I think it should (Rigify)
I am starting to learn character rigging and I created an amature for a character (Based of the human amature samples). When I generate a rig out of it I don't understand why the hands are staying at the same place, even if I turn of IK. Do I have to change something in the settings?
I found some rig tutorials but in 4.2 the settings are a little bit different and I don't now how to fix it.
I also want to have the "hands" pulled after the body. So its more like they are hovering under the main Part of the body.


Your question makes me think that you're confusing Metarig and Rig: after generating the rig, you should hide the metarig.
If you want to see the deforming bones, you have to turn on the visibility of the "DEF" Bones collection: theese are the bones to use when weight painting.
In my example the DEF-hand.L bone is selected, which has been moved by the IK chain.


Sorry for my late response. I didn't hide the metarig, but I was just using the rig in pose mode. My problem was, that the hands of the rig are staying in the same place when I moved the head in any direction.
With the metarig I could move the headbone it in any direction and the rest was following "normally" (FK) also the hands were damp tracked (With influence 0.5) to the connecting bone. This was also not working anymore when I created the rig
